# External Openshift 4.13 DNS Resolving As If Local

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, coredns

I have an Openshift 4.13 SNO set up and all was working well until yesterday.  The timing seemed like after I installed and subsequently removed cert-manager, but all DNS requests from a container are coming back as the Openshift Node (192.168.2.11).  After using a dnsutils container and running an nslookup on google.com, I get the following output:

```
# nslookup google.com
Server:         172.30.0.10
Address:        172.30.0.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com.*cluster*.*domain*.com
Address: 192.168.2.11
```

Clearly, all lookups are coming back as subdomains of my cluster and pointing to my local node.  I can verify this by every external request of my containers erroring out with the Application is not Available screen.

EDIT:
One step closer to an answer, I think.  If I remove my domain and cluster.domain.com from the search line of my /etc/resolv.conf dns resolution seems to work.  I sadly don't know enough about DNS or Openshift/K8s to know what to do with this information

Comment: can you add how `/etc/resolv.conf` file of a pod looks like to the question? and `coredns` `ConfigMap` in `kube-system` namespace? have you added any rewrite rules to Corefile?